# How to retrieve data from dictionaries contained in a pandas dataframe column from each row

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have some data in the following format (headers are: 'ID' which is an integer, and 'feature' which is in a dictionary layout but I think it's an object type according to type() function):

```
ID      feature
862     [{'id': 931, 'name': 'blue'}, {'id': 4290, 'name': 'black'}
8844    [{'id': 10090, 'name': 'red'}, {'id': 10941, 'name': 'yellow'}
...     ...
```

```py
print(pd.concat([df['ID'], pd.json_normalize(df['keywords'])],axis=1))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

I also tried the below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[y['name'] for y in x] for x in df['keywords']], index=df.index)
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The final output that I am looking for is:

```
ID      feature
862     blue, black
8844    red, yellow
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

if your data is in string format then you can try regex

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
def func(string):
    return re.findall("'name': '(\w+)'", string)

columns = ['ID','feature']
data = [['862',"{'id': 931, 'name': 'blue'}, {'id': 4290, 'name': 'black'}"],
['8844',"{'id': 10090, 'name': 'red'}, {'id': 10941, 'name': 'yellow'}"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df["feature_colors"] = df["feature"].apply(func)
print(df[["ID", "feature_colors"]])
```

outputs:

```
     ID feature_colors
0   862  [blue, black]
1  8844  [red, yellow]
```

or use json

```
import json
def func2(string):
    json_lst = json.loads(string)
    lst = []
    for el in json_lst:
        lst.append(el["name"])
    return lst
```